# Is there a std:: function which is usable as a predicate (similar to std::is_null_ptr)?

Tags: c++, null-pointer

I had hoped for a short, concise, elegant:

```
std::array<int*,10> ip_arr;
bool all_null = std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(),ip_arr.end(),std::is_null_ptr_as_fn);
```

instead of inventing a lambda for that purpose:

```
std::array<int*,10> ip_arr;
bool all_null = std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(),ip_arr.end(),[](int *ip){ return ip == nullptr;});
```

which may even be suspicious because I ignored `std::is_null_ptr` and instead it should read like:

```
std::array<int*,10> ip_arr;
bool all_null = std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(),ip_arr.end(),[](int *ip){ std::is_null_ptr r(ip); return r();});
```

Yuck.

Comment: cppreference.com has a nice list of all C++ library functions. Did you find anything there?

Comment: `std::is_null_ptr` does not exist. In case you refer to `std::is_null_pointer`, thats something different, not what you think it is. There is no use for it here

Comment: frankly, this looks like a self made *problem*. There is no problem other than overthinking something simple. Your code, the second variant, the one that works, is completely fine.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, you are correct on both. It was late and for a beginner it is hard to grasp the intention behind `is_null_pointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library provides several function objects for arithmetic and logical operations: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional

You can use `logical_not` to detect pointer null-ness.

```cpp
bool all_null = std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), std::logical_not{});
```

Note that we're passing an instance of the function object (using `{}` or `()` to instance it).

---

As indicated by other answers and comments however, the lambda in your second code snippet might be considered more readable, with clearer intent, without relying on implicit [pointer-to-bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) conversion.

If you're seeking conciseness for this, or any other lambda predicate, you could name it for re-use:

```cpp
auto is_null = [](auto *t) { return t == nullptr; };
```

```cpp
bool all_null = std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), is_null);
```

or composition with other function objects:

```
bool all_null = std::none_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), std::not_fn(is_null));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::indentity` from C++20. As pointers can be implicitly converted to bool,

```
std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), std::identity());
```

will test if all pointers are **not** nullptrs.

To test if all pointers are null (as you are asking), you can use `any_of` and negate the result:

```
not std::any_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), std::identity());
```

of invert the `std::indentity` result:

```
std::all_of(ip_arr.begin(), ip_arr.end(), std::not_fn(std::identity()));
```

Although your code with lambda may be more readable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `std::is_null_ptr`. In case you refer to `std::is_null_pointer`, its a type trait to check if some type is `nullptr_t`. You have an array of `int*` there is no `nullptr_t` anywhere, the trait is of no help here.

Your version with the lambda is ok. Thats what lambdas were invented for. Do not expect to find functions for everything in the standard library.

PS: Also your request for a `std::function` is a little misguided. `std::function` is what you need for type erased callables. For example you want to store pointer to free function, an instance of a lambda, or others in the same variable, then you use a `std::function`. If you do not need type erasure, then you do not need `std::function`. `std::function` is not the type to be used whenever you pass functions around. Admittedly its name can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I didn't mention `std::function` at all in my question - still a bit uneasy with the conception of it. "Standard library function object" was an edit not made by me - I asked for a simple, global predicate function originally. Should that edit better be taken back or is the question as a whole now of higher quality?

Comment: @Vroomfondel original title "Is there a std:: function which is usable as a predicate (similar to std::is_null_ptr)?"

Comment: @Vroomfondel yes that edit should be taken back imho. I saw it in the queue and rejected, because I knew it will render part of my answer into not making sense.

Comment: @Vroomfondel nevermind, I can remove my PS, but it has a bit of a bad taste to invest in an answer just to throw it away because the question gets edited

Comment: @Vroomfondel actually also your edit about striking `std_is_null_ptr` is not a nice edit. Quesitons are for the misunderstandings, for the broken code, for the silly stuff. Don't be ashamed. THe corrections are for answers, not for the question

Comment: @Vroomfondel i considered it again.... the edits did not improve things much, but did a bit of damage, so I rolled them back

Comment: I feel I should remark `std::is_null_ptr` as erroneous, otherwise C++ beginner users are misled to believe this is a real thing, no?

Comment: @Vroomfondel as i said, the question is for the misunderstandings and for the broken Code. Of course if someone reads the question but not the answer they miss something

Comment: @Vroomfondel btw only now I realize that you are asking for a `std::`  function, not necessarily for a `std::function`. :D Anyhow, I think I made my point clear, and eventually its your question, your edits. I just want to ask you to ping me in case you rolllback my rollback so I can adjust this answer accordingly.